Riverpod ref.read calls build method and returns initial state
In my flutter app I want to use InAppWebView and riverpod , So I created :
@riverpod
class WebViewController extends _$WebViewController {
  @override
  InAppWebViewController? build() {
    return null;
  }

  void setController(InAppWebViewController controller) {
    state = controller;
    debugPrint('WebViewController set: $controller');
  }
}

and when WebView was created I set controller :
 onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
  webViewController = controller;
  ref
      .read(webViewControllerProvider.notifier)
      .setController(controller);
},

I created other provider
@riverpod
class CursorController extends _$CursorController {
  static const double STEP_SIZE = 10.0;

  @override
  CursorState build() {
    // Initialize at center of screen
    final size = window.physicalSize;
    return CursorState(position: Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2));
  }

  void initializePosition() {
    final size = window.physicalSize;
    state = CursorState(position: Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2));
    _updateCursor();
  }

  void _updateCursor() {
    // Use read on the notifier to access the current state without rebuilding
    final webViewController =
        ref.read(webViewControllerProvider.notifier).state;
    if (webViewController == null) {

I am using KeyboardListener to detect keyboard events , so when I press left arrow I am calling _updateCursor() , the issue is when I call ref.read(webViewControllerProvider.notifier).state , the state is null because :
  InAppWebViewController? build() {
    return null;
  }

is called again. why? how can I prevent it and return state ?

Haven't able to look into the details yet, it's likely you need turn auto disposal to off. @Riverpod(keepAlive: true)

yes with keepalive, it is ok, but why is my WebViewController disposed?

You can access a state by simply ref.read(webViewControllerProvider). Anyway, this looks like an ephemeral state. Are you sure you want to use a provider for that?

what is your suggestion ?

You can just store the controller in a variable in the State class of the StatefulWidget

you are right, I guess class WebViewState {
final InAppWebViewController? controller;
const WebViewState({this.controller});
WebViewState copyWith({InAppWebViewController? controller}) {
return WebViewState(controller: controller ?? this. Controller);
}
} approach is better , thanks

then I can create an instance from webviewstate and set controller WebViewState().copyWith(controller: controller). then in CursorController I can get controller
